# Extraneous output when using an unlimited format item

Tags: fortran, gfortran

This is my code:

```
Program Output_Format

Implicit none

Integer::k
Integer,parameter:: Br_nn_mre = 5
Character(56),parameter:: FMT_01 = '(1x,"NN_DM:",1x,*("NN_",i2.2,1x))'

Open( 15 , File = 'Output.txt' , Status = 'Unknown' , Action = 'Write' )

  Write( 15 , FMT_01 ) ( k , k = 1 , Br_nn_mre )

Close( 15 , Status = 'Keep' )

End Program Output_Format
```

The content of `Output.txt` file is:

```
NN_DM: NN_01 NN_02 NN_03 NN_04 NN_05 NN_
```

I want to get this content in `Output.txt`:

```
NN_DM: NN_01 NN_02 NN_03 NN_04 NN_05
```

That is, without the trailing `NN_`

What is wrong with `*` IN `FMT_01` format? For example if I put a `5` in place of `*` I will get what I want.  How can I use the unlimited repeat count and still get the desired output?  I won't always know how many times to repeat.

Comment: Yes, i want to remove that trailing and I want to us
 `*` always because i do not want to think what is the value of `Br_nn_mre`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to how formats are processed, and in particular, when a data transfer statement terminates.

For an output statement such as you have, transfer terminates when either:

- a data edit descriptor is reached and there is no remaining element in the output list; or
- the final closing parenthesis is reached and there is no remaining element in the output list.

In your formats

```
'(1x,"NN_DM:",1x,*("NN_",i2.2,1x))'
```

and

```
'(1x,"NN_DM:",1x,5("NN_",i2.2,1x))'
```

the single data edit descriptor there is the `i2.2`.  The `1x`s are control edit descriptors and the `"NN_DM"` and `"NN_"` are character string edit descriptors.

Let's look at how your format is processed in the case of `5` as the repeat count.  The first part of the format `1x,"NN_DM:",1x` is processed without issue giving output `NN_DM:` moving us on to `5("NN_",i2.2,1x))`.  Corresponding to this repeated fragment are five data items, so they are processed (giving output `NN_01 NN_02 NN_03 NN_04 NN_5`).

The important part is what happens next.  After completing this `5(..)` part we reach the final closing parenthesis of the format specification *and there is no remaining output item*,  so processing of the format comes to an end.

What's different with the `*(..)` case?

Well, when we reach the end of `*(..)` we go back round to the start of that repeated format; we don't move on to the final closing parenthesis.<sup>1</sup>  That leaves us to process the edit descriptors until we reach a data edit descriptor.  This means that `"NN_"` is processed (resulting in `NN_` being output) before we notice that we are out of data items for output.

Coming to the fix: use the colon edit descriptor. The colon edit descriptor acts like a data edit descriptor in the sense that format processing terminates immediately if there is no remaining data item.

```
Character(56),parameter:: FMT_01 = '(1x,"NN_DM:",1x,*("NN_",i2.2,:,1x))'
```

Personally, I would write this as

```
Character(*),parameter:: FMT_01 = '(" NN_DM:",*(" NN_",i2.2,:))'
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This would be no different if we had `6` as the repeat count; `*` isn't special except that it is a "very large repeat count".